# How to debug this situation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

When a page is loaded some extra information loads by AJAX-request then is displayed, so a piece of DOM is dynamically generated. After that in some cases (I don't know why but occasionally it happens) part of this dynamically loaded DOM is modified. 
So, when page is loaded only container is present:

```
<div id = "container"></div>
```

After AJAX-request in looks like the following:

```
<div id = "container">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

And if an extra modification is made, structure turns out to be like this:

```
<div id = "container">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I need to find out which code makes this modification.

I could use a DOM-breakpoint if this HTML was static but it's not the case.
Another idea is to pause execution right after the HTML is generated and put DOM-breakpoint then but I don't think it will help me due to the following reasons:

1. Mysterious modification does not happen very often, so I will have to make this procedure many times.
2. Pausing execution might alter the sequence in which different pieces of code works, so I might be unable to reproduce this situation.

I also can't use debug messages because there is a lot of JS-code and I have no idea where the modification is made.

I feel that there must be a straight way to do this but I can't find it. Will be grateful for any advise.

Comment: How much code do you have? Could you share all of it, maybe we could find the part that's doing the mystery modification. If it's too much, could you just share the ajax code?

Comment: I'd use the [Timeline](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool) with JSProfile (if you want deep detail of every call). This will show you what happens at every frame. So when you see the DOM has changed, just stop the recording and look at the last frames to see what JS was executed.

Comment: Look at the data that was entered when your P tags get empty. It may be some XSS phishing stuff, browsers will remove some code that is vulnarable.